# Can I view my friends' questions on Facebook Questions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-questions

Is there a way to view all questions that have been posted by my friends on Facebook questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact now the default when you click on the question tab.

Answer (score -1):

You just go to "Activity Log" on your facebook page, and than choose tab "question" and there you will see all the question that you asked. 
It is simple as that :)

Comment: The question was about how to find questions posted by friends of the asker, not the asker.